# What's the socket protocol with value 17?

Tags: c, sockets, int, protocols, reverse-engineering

Recall the declaration of a socket in C has the following signature:

```
int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);
```

I met some reverse-engineered code where protocol = 17. Does anyone know what protocol this refers to? The net seems to be lacking of such `int` values; they have only the names, at best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protocol 17 would be UDP per [IANA specifications](http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml), which is referred to at least in the Linux [socket](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) documentation. The name of the protocol should also be available via [getprotoent](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getprotoent.3.html) if it’s supported by the platform.

Microsoft also uses same numbers for the protocols in [socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket).

Comment: So the usual `0` value is "IPv6 Hop-by-Hop Option"? Or is it the default value that this table doesn't show?

Comment: @ZiruiWang That is a good question, why did they make zero have some meaning. I added links to more information on at least Linux, they also say zero is default to the type and not what IANA says.

Comment: 0 is indeed the "default" protocol for the `type` of socket being created. For instance, the default for `SOCK_STREAM` is `IPPROTO_TCP` (6), and the default for `SOCK_DGRAM` is `IPPROTO_UDP` (17).